# how can i extract using regex in java

Tags: java

I need to extract the extract this string as 2 document  `example   test(s): testing`
one is example and the other is testing ...please tell me how can i extract it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.split()` method to split the function to split words from sentence.

Example.

```
String sentence = "example tests(s): testing";
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

for (String word: words) {
   system.out.println(word);
}
```

Found the example here: http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/03/split-string-into-words-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to first come up with a pattern to match your input. Once you do that, and if the pattern doesn't do it already, simply put `(...)` brackets around the pattern that matches the part you're interested in. This creates what is called capturing groups.

With `java.util.regex.Matcher`, you can get what each group captured using the `group(int)` method.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Brackets for Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), [Repeating a Capturing Group vs Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)

---

#### Example

Given this test string:

```
i have 35 dogs, 16 cats and 10 elephants
```

Then `(\d+) (cats|dogs)` yields 2 match results ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/b4AIq5CxQP))

- Result 1: `35 dogs`

  - Group 1 captures `35`
  - Group 2 captures `dogs`
- Result 2: `16 cats`

  - Group 1 captures `16`
  - Group 2 captures `cats`